# Pass multiple Field Values and submit through HTML Link

Tags: javascript, html

There is a website that I do not have access to on the back-end that I go to monthly, type in my email address, check a few boxes and hit a submit button.

A while ago I found out You can append

```
?fieldname=value
```

to the end of the url to have it automatically fill that value into the field with that name. But is there anyway I can expand on this and fill in multiple values and hit the submit button?

Thanks!

Comment: you can add multiple parameters seperated with & like ?name=John&age=30&gender=male

Answer (score 1):

Adding ?fieldname1=fieldvalue1&fieldname2=fieldvalue2  etc.. can add many more parameters send to the server.

Some website use those parameters in the page so when you add the good parameters, you will get the page with the modifications that those parameters did on it.